# How to Iterate through a list of dataframes in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframes, combined into a list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [1, 2, 3], 'colors': ['red', 'white', 'blue']})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [7, 44, 93], 'colors': ['red', 'white', 'blue']})

df_list = [df,df1]
```

I would like to use a for loop, to iterate through them, and print each number.
For this, I tried:

```
for num in df_list.numbers.unique():
    val = locals()[num]
    print(val)
```

But get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'numbers'
```

I also tried, more simply:

```
for num in df_list.numbers.unique():
    print(num)
```

But get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'numbers'
```

Similar questions were asked, without satisfactory responses.

Comment: `df_list` is just a list. You might want double for loop. One for looping through `df_list`, one for `num` within each `df` inside `df_list`.

Comment: why are you printing the data ? is it for some homework exercise or is there a real world problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Manakin This is for a real problem. I generated sample data, but in reality, the functions I use are more complex than printing. Printing numbers is just a convenient tool for the example. I figured that if printing works, other functions within the loop will work.

Comment: then I recommend not using any loops, after printing the data what is the outcome?

Comment: @Manakin The final outcome would be to rename each dataframe with a distinct name, so each one is ready for a separate round of analyses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Option A: Iterating over a value from list of dataframes

Since you have two dataframes you will have to

- Iterate throught the dataframes one by one
- Then, for each dataframe (`df_tmp`), iterate over all the unique numbers

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [1, 2, 3], 'colors': ['red', 'white', 'blue']})
   ...: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [7, 44, 93], 'colors': ['red', 'white', 'blue']})

In [3]: df_list = [df,df1]

In [4]: for df_tmp in df_list:
   ...:     for num in df_tmp['numbers'].unique():
   ...:         print(num)
   ...:
1
2
3
7
44
93
```

***Note**: Using this approach, the values will not necessarily be unique!* (for example if you have `2` in both, `df['numbers']` and `df1['numbers']`, it would be printed twice).

#### Option B: Merging the dataframes before iterating

Sometimes it might be more useful to create another dataframe which has all your dataframes combined. You can do it with [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)<sup>1</sup> like this:

```
In [17]: df_new = pd.concat(df_list)

In [18]: df_new
Out[18]:
   numbers colors
0        1    red
1        2  white
2        3   blue
0        7    red
1       44  white
2       93   blue
```

Then, you could iterate over all the unique elements in `'numbers'` by simply:

```
In [19]: for num in df_new['numbers'].unique():
    ...:     print(num)
    ...:
1
2
3
7
44
93
```

- This will guarantee that the numbers are *unique*. The down side is that if all you need to do is to iterate over unique elements of a column that exists in multiple dataframes, creating a new dataframe is a bit of overhead. This brings be to option C.

#### Option C: Iterating over just the unique values

- If all you want to do is to iterate over the unique elements in one column which exists in multiple dataframes, you do not need a temporary dataframe for that. Instead, you can achieve the same thing by just taking the union of sets of the elements

```
# or: nums = set().union(*(map(lambda x:set(x['numbers']), (df, df1))))
In [30]: nums = set().union(*(set(df_['numbers']) for df_ in (df, df1)))

In [31]: nums
Out[31]: {1, 2, 3, 7, 44, 93}

In [32]: for num in nums:
    ...:     print(num)
    ...:
1
2
3
7
44
93
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The `pd.concat()` takes an iterable (for example, a list, tuple or generator) as the first argument and returns a brand new dataframe which you can use.

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to iterate over the list. the list items are dfs not numbers.
you should concat the dfs:

```
dfs_list=pd.concat(df_list)
```

dfs_list lokks like this:

```
    numbers colors
  0  1      red
  1  2      white
  2  3      blue
  0  7      red
  1  44    white
  2  93     blue
```

and now the loop will work:

```
for num in dfs_list.numbers.unique():
print(num)
1
2
3
7
etc...
```